# How to make a font family with the font file in its own folder

Tags: fonts, luatex, fontspec, overleaf, folders

I have uploaded the TTF font file `EBGaramond-Regular.ttf` to my Overleaf document and am compiling with LuaLaTeX. I would like to move the font file into a folder called `Fonts`. How can I change these commands

```
\usepackage{fontspec}
\newfontfamily\garafont{EBGaramond-Regular.ttf}
```

so that Overleaf knows how to find the `.ttf` file in my `Font` folder?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
\newfontfamily\garafont[Path=./Fonts/]{EBGaramond-Regular.ttf}
```

The `Path` has to end with a `/` as it is just appended when it looks for the file.